# opencv_createsamples command it is not recognized in pycharm

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I just started fiddling with opencv and python using pycharm. I followed a tutorial on how to create a Haar Cascade file, but when I reached the step where I had to use 'opencv_createsamples' command, it returned:

> "is not recognized as an internal or external command"

I searched for a solution. Most of them said to add opencv to path in the enviroment variables, so I downloaded opencv, extracted it in the C directory and added it to the path, but it still did not work. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this a quickie and I got the same message. I also use PyCharm. Are you sure you're using the right version of opencv? I'm on 2.4 which is quite old. Maybe this is a method that's been added in a later version. If you can import cv2 it shouldn't be the pythonpath.

Comment: I tried using the latest version 4.0.i could import it so  it 's not the path, thanks for the answer .

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you'd vote for my answer if you found it helpful :)